# Cannot download package files

Tags: package-management

`Synaptic package manager` is freezing when it attempts to download packages for installation.

I have tried to install using `terminal`, but I keep receiving a message saying: 'connection failed' 
'unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?'

My internet connection is fine, what has gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm only used to debian and apt, but I guess it must be the same.

When you try `apt-get update` it shows which server(s) it try to connect to.
Are those servers reachable?
Is apt set up to use a proxyserver which is not running?

These settings are under /etc/apt, for instance /etc/apt/sources.list or /etc/apt/apt.conf.d

---

Update:
ign: means apt for some reason ignores the repository.

Try 

`cd /var/lib/apt
mv lists lists.old
mkdir lists
apt-get update`

Try 
`set | grep -i proxy
grep -sir proxy /etc/apt`

If it lists any proxy, is it responsive?

---

Update:
So the the settings say there is supposed to run a HTTP_PROXY on port 4001

Either start it, if you know what it is, or remove the references to it.
It could be set in your `~/.profile`, `/etc/profile` or `~/.bashrc`
Or in your network settings.

For now, do a `unset HTTP_PROXY` and the other proxy-related keywords.

---

See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030454/removing-proxy-for-apt

Comment: they aren't connecting. I just get Ign:1, Ign:2, Ign3: etc before each server ie: Ign:68 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages. I cant understand why I am getting no connection to the servers. Have had no problems installing packages either through synaptic or terminal until now.

Comment: i tried to install another programme and 'cannot connect to local host' blinked momentarity on terminal...

Comment: See my updated answer above.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion but no joy. $ set | grep -i proxy returned
HTTP_PROXY='http://localhost:4001 ' and a whole list of stuff but when I tried $ grep -sir proxy /etc/apt still nothing. I have a proxy configuration in my network settings if that is of any use?

Comment: $ sudo apt-get update gives following info:
0% [Connecting to localhost (127.0.0.1)] unable to connect to localhost:4001:

Comment: See updated response; it is not possible to have formetted comments.